# convert pandas.DataFrame to a two-dimensional array

Tags: python, pytest

here is the print of pandas.Dataframe that I got like this `tests = pd.read_csv('tsur.tsv', sep='\t')`

```
                                                  query  match
0                                        jordan belfort  False
1       Ricardo Jalone Bob FRANK\n\n1\nLondon Markus  False
2                                        USA Maria JOHN  False
```

how i can get two-dimensional array like this

```
[(jordan belfort, False), (Ricardo Jalone Bob FRANK\n\n1\nLondon Markus, False), (USA Maria JOHN, False)]
```

I am writing pytest tests and will introduce this into the pytest.fixture